# how to efficiently make a mini-batch of images in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, resnet, mini-batch

I am trying to calculate a forward pass using pre-trained ResNet model in pytorch. I am having trouble creating a 4-d Tensor of mini-batches. Can someone please tell what is the proper way to do that?

EDIT: I changed the code and it works now. However, I still think there should a more efficient way of doing this.

Here's my code:

```
import pickle
import json
import shutil
import Image
import torchvision.models as models
import torchvision.transformers as transformers
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch import Tensor
import glob
import torch

batch_size = 128
im_size = 299

normalize = transforms.Normalize(
   mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
   std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
)
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
   transforms.Scale(im_size),
   transforms.CenterCrop(im_size),
   transforms.ToTensor(),
   normalize
])


model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

d_batch = make_batch(imgs, batch_size)

dtype = torch.FloatTensor
tmp = Variable(torch.randn(batch_size, 3, im_size, im_size).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)


for batch in tqdm(batches):
        try:
                data = [Image.open(img) for img in batch]
                for idx, item in enumerate(data):
                        tmp[idx] = preprocess(item)
                batch_result = model(tmp)
        except Exception,x:
                print x
```

Comment: You can create a 4d Tensor like this: torch.Tensor(1,1,1,1). Or to add a dimension to any tensor (or Variable) you can do t.unsqueeze(0). But not sure how this will help you. You need to give us the error, or more hints where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Have you tried DataLoader(you can find it in torch.utils.data) in pytorch?? It makes minibatches for you using multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

Using `dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(...)` you can load a dataset from image folder. After that you can use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batchSize)` to specify mini-batch size and other things for further processing.